# What is the 'libzimpl-NOTFOUND' Error that occurs during the installation of SCIP

Tags: scip

I want to run GCG thus I downloaded the scipoptsuite-6.0.0.tgz and did `tar xvzf scipoptsuite-6.0.0.tgz` in Ubuntu/Linux. I replaced some documents with the second patch files `scipoptsuite-6.0.0_patch01.tgz`. Then I configured the build:

```
`cmake ..`
```

but it said

`The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found: *BISON *FLEX * IPOPT * Criterion* PkgConfig* GSL* CLIQUER* HMETIS* BLISSot`.

Then I continued compiling: `make`. It failed and reported:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'libzimpl-NOTFOUND', needed by 'bin/scip'. 
Stop.
////CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1488: recipe fortarget'scip/src/CMakeFiles/scip.dir/all' failed
  ////make[1]: *** [scip/src/CMakeFiles/scip.dir/all] Error 2
  /////Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2.
```

What should I do next? I tried directly installed the GCG using the scipoptsuite, but met the same Error.  How can I solve this error and find the missing packages mentioned above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is a question under the topic of SCIP installation issue. I am looking forward to some replies.

Comment: I am happy that you already switched to Linux since your last question. Have you tried to follow [the GCG installation guide](http://gcg.or.rwth-aachen.de/doc/INSTALL.html)? Cmake won't work because GCG does not support it (yet). On your way, you will need to install some additional libraries using `sudo apt-get install libbison-dev` etc.

Comment: I tried this morning following :# tar xvfz scipoptsuite-[version].tgz
# cd scipoptsuite-[version]/
# make
# make gcg. There are still several errors. Such as, Makefile：402：recipe for target 'mainfiles' failed.. It shows "**Build complete", but when I type $ gcg in the ':command-line interface', No response. This confused me because after installing scipoptsuite, I could start the software by typing "$ scip" then enter that program: scip>. What is the problem with the gcg I installed.